# Cardinality of $l_{\infty}$ is c

Tags: functional-analysis

I need to show that **the cardinality of $l_{\infty}$ is $c$, the cardinality of the continuum**, where $l_{\infty}$ is the space of all bounded real sequences.

Any hint is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Recall that $\ell_\infty$ is a subset of $\Bbb{R^N}$, the set of *all* sequences. Now use cardinal arithmetics.